# phpMyadmin showing code instead of GUI on Ubuntu

Tags: apache2, phpmyadmin

Please do not refer me to other pages, since I have read them all, and they didn't help. I need someone with experience who can help me.

I have purged and re-installed apache2, PHP 7.4 and phpmyadmin, and when I type localhost/phpmyadmin in the browser, it shows php code. I have tried everything.
In apache2.conf, I configured :

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

In mime.conf, I configured :

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

PHP7.4 module is installed and enabled (via a2enmod )

Web server is working. I created a file in /var/www/html that contains php code :`<?php echo("Success"); ?>,` and the page is runnning successfully.

I don't know what else to do. Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: nobody has the solution to this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange, it started working by itself.I guess it needed a reboot after all installations and settings.

So , in conclusion if anyone has this issue, he should do the following :

1). purge and re-install apache2,php and phpmyadmin.

2). install php module and enable it in apache2

3). make sure in mime.conf there is configuration for php files

4). upgrade your system

5). restart apache 2 server and restart machine several times.